# Aggregation of two collections in MongoDB

Tags: json, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have two collections, that I'm trying to do some kind of lookup for. I'm not 100% sure how to approach it.

**Collection 1: Employees**

```
{
 "data": [
  {
     "full name": "Keith Richards",
     "age": 21,
     "userName": "keith1@keith.com",
     "employeeDetails": {
        "id": 102522
    }
  },
  {
    "full name": "Jim Morrison",
     "age": 27,
     "userName": "jim@jim.com",
     "employeeDetails": {
        "id": 135522
    }
  }
 ]
}
```

**Collection 2: Entries**

```
{
 "data": [
  {
     "dateCreated": "02-04-2016",
     "billable": true,
     "minutes": 150,
     "employeeId": {
        "id": 102522
        }
  },
  {
     "dateCreated": "03-04-2016",
     "billable": true,
     "minutes": 250,
     "employeeId": {
        "id": 102522
   }
  },
  {
     "dateCreated": "04-04-2016",
     "billable": true,
     "minutes": 20,
     "employeeId": {
        "id": 135522
   }
  }
]
}
```

As you can see **employeeDetails.id** from the collection **Employees** matched that of **employeeId.id** from the **Entries** collection.

I'm trying to do a lookup so that I can match the id from Entries to a user name in Employees, so I can match a name with an entry, desired results below:

```
{
 "data": [
  {
     "full name": "Keith Richards",
     "dateCreated": "02-04-2016",
     "minutes": 150,
     "employeeId": {
        "id": 102522
        }
  },
  {
     "full name": "Keith Richards",
     "dateCreated": "03-04-2016",
     "minutes": 250,
     "employeeId": {
        "id": 102522
        }
  },
  {
     "full name": "Jim Morrison",
     "dateCreated": "04-04-2016",
     "minutes": 20,
     "employeeId": {
        "id": 135522
  }
 }
]
}
```

This would allow me to get an end result of a group/sum:

- Full name: Keith Richards
- Mins: 400
- Full name: Jim Morrison
- Mins: 20

I have tried a bunch, the only thing coming near to working is the following:

```
db.getCollection('entries')
.aggregate(
  [
    {
      "$lookup": {
        "from": "employees", 
        "localField": "trafficEmployeeId.id", 
        "foreignField": "employeeDetails.id", 
        "as": "employees_loaded"
      }
    }
  ]
);
```

This basically gives me a collection with two different arrays.

Can anyone give me advice / solution on the best way to approach what I'm trying to achieve? I went with MongoDB as the input relies heavily on JSON input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to include the content of `data` array itself as the collection items. For example your `employees` collection should look like :

```
{
    "full name": "Keith Richards",
    "age": 21,
    "userName": "keith1@keith.com",
    "employeeDetails": {
        "id": 102522
    }
}, {
    "full name": "Jim Morrison",
    "age": 27,
    "userName": "jim@jim.com",
    "employeeDetails": {
        "id": 135522
    }
}
```

This way you can `$lookup` easily like this :

```
db.entries.aggregate(
    [
        { $unwind: "$data" }, {
            $lookup: {
                "from": "employees",
                "localField": "data.employeeId.id",
                "foreignField": "employeeDetails.id",
                "as": "employees_loaded"
            }
        }, {
            $unwind: "$employees_loaded"
        }, {
            $group: {
                "_id": 1,
                "data": {
                    $push: {
                        "full name": "$employees_loaded.full name",
                        "dateCreated": "$data.dateCreated",
                        "minutes": "$data.minutes",
                        "employeeId": "$data.employeeId"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    ]
);
```

The `$unwind` is used to remove `employees_loaded` array generated from the `$lookup`. The `$group` stage is used to get the field you want to keep and `$push` them into an array called `data`

Comment: Thank you so much! - This got me a lot closer. The issue is, is that it has given me 4 arrays, full name, dateCreated, minutes and employeeId. They are just listed, but don't match up. Would I need to wrap the above in a 'Match' or function?

Link to example here: http://i.imgsafe.org/e2ff25c59c.png

Comment: Do you want to match a specific userName or employeeId ?

Comment: Both collections have the employeeId, but only the Employee collection has the user name. I want to be able to match the userName from Employee to the employeeId in the Entries collection.

This way, I can output a list of entires (minutes) and have each one show the userName.

Comment: In your entries collection do you have moved data array item to the collection itself  like in the employee collection ?

Comment: No, they are in separate collections, as per the JSON examples at the top of the post.

Comment: I've updated my post and find [this gist](https://gist.github.com/bertrandmartel/46d3dd1e8e159c603c6cb087b8055aa5) to compare your input database and output result

Comment: Thanks! It's close, however instead of matching the User Names, it's putting all names in one array. I have updated the gist with a comment.

I really appreciate your help!

Comment: Thank you! - It seems to be only be giving me an array of Minutes. I have updated the gist